# QGIS won't open ANY shapefile or geopackage

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geopackage, invalid-data

Running a clean install of QGIS 3.22.10 on a Lenovo laptop running Windows 10.

I cannot open any shapefile. Every time I try to open one I get the following error message:

*Invalid Data Source: xxx.shp is not a valid or recognized data source.*

I have checked all the files (.shp, .shx, .dbf, .prj) are together in the same folder and the correct CRS is set. I have also tried both drag & drop as well as the Layer --> Add Layer --> Add Vector Layer menu.

I have checked all shapefiles on other laptops running the same version of QGIS in Windows 10 and they work perfectly fine.

I have tried adding the files to a Geopackage, which I then verified on different machines and it worked fine. However on the said laptop it gives the same error message.

I have also tried reinstalling the same version of QGIS, as well as other versions. Same result, nothing will open shapefiles.

To make things more confusing, I do have a basemap of the UK saved as a .qgz which QGIS opens with no problem and works fine.

Comment: delete (or create a new) profile and try again